# Random matrices may be asymptotically free but never free themselves?

Tags: pr.probability, oa.operator-algebras, random-matrices, free-probability

It is well known that independent $N\times N$ unitarily-invariant random matrices (or independent families of random matrices) may be asymptotically free as $N\to \infty$ with respect to the expectation of the normalized trace, under some assumptions on their own convergence. I recall reading somewhere however that for fixed $N$ it is not possible to meet the criteria for freeness exactly. This is to say something like: if $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ are random $N\times N$ matrices $\text{Mat}_N(L)$ whose entries have finite moments of all orders $L = \bigcap_{p \ge1} L^p(\Omega,\mathbb{C})$, if the $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ are independent and $A_i \notin \mathbb{C}I_N$, then setting
$$
\phi(X) = \mathbb{E}\left( \frac1N \text{Tr}(X) \right)
$$
we cannot have precisely that
$$
\left.
\begin{array}{c}
P_j \in \mathbb{C}\langle X \rangle  \\
\phi(P_j(A_{i_j})) = 0 \\
i_1 \neq i_2 \neq \ldots \neq i_n
\end{array}
\right\}
\implies
\phi\left( P_1(A_{i_1}) \cdots P_n(A_{i_n}) \right)=0
$$
I cannot find an exact reference for this statement, is it obvious?

Comment: Just consider the case $N=1$ and $\phi(A_1A_2A_1A_2)$

Comment: I think OP is asking if this is true for any fixed $N$.

Comment: For general N, the same example (even in the Gaussian case), but more tedious computation.

Comment: It is not clear that it must always be impossible though. Perhaps there is some N and some non-trivial (and non-Gaussian) random matrices that satisfy $\phi(A_1A_2A_1A_2) - \phi(A_1)^2\phi(A_2^2) - \phi(A_1^2)\phi(A_2)^2+\phi(A_1)^2\phi(A_2)^2=0$

Comment: Actually, there is a non-trivial situation which can be realized in finite-dimensional random matrices,namely the case of two free projections. For this see the paper of Dykema "[Free Products of Hyperfinite von Neumann algebras and free dimension][1]", Theorem 1.1.

  [1]: https://arxiv.org/pdf/funct-an/9211013.pdf